# Divergence of this integral

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln(x)}\text{d}x$$

I tried to justify the divergence with $\ln(x) \leq x-1$ hence $\frac{1}{\ln(x)} \geq \frac{1}{x-1}$

whence

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln(x)}\ \text{d}x \geq \int_0^1 \frac{\text{d}x}{x-1}$$

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\text{d}x}{x-1} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_0^{1 - \epsilon} \frac{1}{x-1}\ \text{d}x = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \ln\vert (1 - \epsilon)-1 \vert - \ln\vert -1\vert = -\infty$$

But how now does this tell me something about the divergence? I mean what I got is

$$-\infty \leq \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln(x)}\ \text{d}x$$

Which doesn't necessarily means the integral diverges.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is rather simple.

Your inequality is initially correct, indeed

$$\ln(x) \leq x-1$$

for all $x > 0$.

On the other side, as Robert Israel pointed out, when you take the reciprocals you have:

$$\frac{1}{\ln(x)} \geq \frac{1}{x-1}$$

Which is correct when $x > 1$. Remember that $x\in(0, 1)$ gives negative outputs from $\ln(x)$, hence when you deal with negative numbers you take the reciprocals, you changes the signs again getting

$$\frac{1}{\ln(x)} \leq \frac{1}{x-1}$$

Which indeed shows you the divergene at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\ln(x) < 0$ for $0 < x < 1$, your inequality is going the wrong way.
Note that $\ln(x) > 2 (x-1)$ for $1-\epsilon < x < 1$ for appropriate values of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Why is going in the wrong way? For $x = 1/10$ I get $\ln(x) = -2.3$ and $x-1 = -0.9$ and it's indeed true that $\ln(1/10) < -9/10$

Comment: $\ln x\leqq x-1$  is true for $x\in(0,1]$.  I think what Robert wants to say is that the opposite inequality is needed in order to show the divergence. @Numb3rs

Comment: Oh I got it now, it's the second parte

Comment: @So_M. Yes, I think he meant the part $\frac{1}{\ln(x)} \geq \frac{1}{x-1}$, which is reversed indeed

Answer (score 0):

I think what you do is not wrong, but that doesn't tell us the divergence.

In my opinion, handling $\ln$ is a bit troublesome, so I prefer to change variables and handle the exponential function.

Changing variable : $t=\log x$, I get $$\int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{\ln x}dx=-\int_0^\infty\dfrac{1}{te^t}dt.$$

Thus it is sufficient to show $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac{1}{te^t}dt=\infty.$

For $\dfrac{1}{te^t}$, both the lower edge $0$ and the upper edge $\infty$ are divergent point, so separate the integral :
$$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{1}{te^t}dt=\int_0^1\dfrac{1}{te^t}dt+\int_1^\infty\dfrac{1}{te^t}dt.$$

Indeed, the second integral $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\dfrac{1}{te^t}dt$ converges but the first integral $\displaystyle\int_0^1\dfrac{1}{te^t}dt$ diverges to infinity, hence we get $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac{1}{te^t}dt=\infty.$

Can you see why $\displaystyle\int_0^1\dfrac{1}{te^t}dt$ diverges to infinity ?